# Restlet stop server after exactly one request is handled

Tags: java, restlet

I want to use [Restlet](http://restlet.com/) to create a local server. This server should receive exaclty one request (besides favicon), and after that request is handled it should shut down. I don't want to use `System.exit`, I want it to shut down properly.

As you can see in my code I commented the line when I assume the request is handled properly. But I can't tell the server to stop there.

How can I tell the server to stop waiting for requests at this point?
I got it working but with 2 issues I'd like to solve.

- I get exceptions when I stop the server within the request
- The `response` sent to the client will not be shown if I stop the server within the request

  ```
  public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args){
      Server serv = null;

      Restlet restlet = new Restlet() {
          @Override
          public void handle(Request request, Response response) {

            if(!request.toString().contains("favicon")){
                System.out.println("do stuff");
                response.setEntity("Request will be handled", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
                //stop server after the first request is handled. 
                //so the program should shut down here
                //if I use serv.stop() here (besides it's currently not final)
                //I'd get exceptions and the user wouldn't see the response
            }
          }
      };



      // Avoid conflicts with other Java containers listening on 8080!
      try {
          serv = new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8182, restlet);

          serv.start();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it. Add a `OnSent` event to the response, and shut down the server here.

```
public class Main {

    private Server serv;

    public Main(){
        run();
    }

    public void run(){

            Restlet restlet = new Restlet() {
                @Override
                public void handle(Request request, Response response) {
                    response.setEntity("Request will be handled", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
                  if(!request.toString().contains("favicon")){
                      System.out.println("do stuff");

                      response.setOnSent(new Uniform() {

                        @Override
                        public void handle(Request req, Response res) {

                            try {
                                serv.stop();//stop the server
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                  }
                }
            };

            // Avoid conflicts with other Java containers listening on 8080!
            try {
                serv = new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8182, restlet);

                serv.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        new Main();

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I think that the way to implement such feature ;-)